# What are the dangers of not conforming to declared HTML doctype?

Tags: dhtml, doctype

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 web site, the `site.master` declares

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

but in the code I have

```
<td class='count-col' data-object-id='<%= Model.ObjectId %>'>
```

1. Am I correct that attribute `data-object-id` is not valid in the declared doctype (XHTML)?
2. What are the downshots of having that violation?
3. What is a good solution for this situation? Should I change DOCTYPE (what would be drawbacks)? Or should I come up with a different way to specify object-id on the element?

Note: object-id is used by a javascript function that shows a popup on `<td>` hover.

Comment: The real danger is that the standards compliance task force may "take you in for questioning" if you know what I mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could give "unexpected" behaviour in older browsers, yet most browsers render it anyways.  That, and your code won't validate, though that should *in the real world* not really stop you.